# Java Applet run under host of file

Tags: java, javascript, applet, embed

I am new here, so cut me some slack if I do something wrong.

I am running a Java Applet in the background of my site as a hidden 'JavaScript iFrame'.  It runs on every page of my site.  Every time I go to a different page it asks me to run it, only under a different url. Example:

[image]

[image]

I want to make it so it just runs under one link, like: Location: example.com/data/btc+.js
Or something along the lines of that.

I know I can click don't show again to automatically run it, but you would need to do that on every page, and it would be annoying to my users.

If you need any more information, just let me know!

TIA